# Pass to fragment using Navigation from Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I have an activity with two fragments. Either fragment is located on container in activity. Also activity has toolbar with settings button. I should pass on settings fragment using Navigation by click on settings button, but i have problems with it, because `findNavController(R.id.home_nav).navigate(R.id.action_second_fragment_to_settings_fragment)`
works if we pass to settings screen and second fragment is active, but from first active will be crash.
What do i need to do for solving this problem? I used just actions in Navigation component for passing between fragment. May be there is useful solution for this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your `navController` in MainActivity, with this code you can access to `navController` and send data to fragment.

load new fragment :

```
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString("id", id)

    (activity as MainActivity).navController.navigate(R.id.orderDetailFragment, bundle)
```

for get data in `onViewCreated`  in fragment :

```
 arguments?.let {

        if (it.getSerializable("id") != null) { 
            val id = it.getString("id")
        }


    }
```

i hope it's useful