# open fragment from activity and pass arguments using navigation components

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

I can navigate from one fragment which is inside of main_graph from navigation components to one activity, I also added the activity inside the main_graph from navigation components:

see the picture below:

[image]

My problem is that I can't navigate from the new activity that was added and send arguments or one bundle to the previous fragment as we can see in the picture of above. This activity is not the MainAcitivity. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61799600/pass-to-fragment-using-navigation-from-activity) and on there the guy did something like this:

```
val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString("id", id)

    (activity as MainActivity).navController.navigate(R.id.orderDetailFragment, bundle)
```

I don't understand why for me not works this code: `(activity as MainActivity)` I think that it should be something like this in my case:

```
        val navController by lazy { findNavController(R.id.main_graph) }

        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("barcode", "123456789")
        navController.navigate(R.id.registerProductFragment, bundle)
```

However I'm getting this error:

```
Process: com.example.inventariooffline, PID: 15859
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.requireViewById(ActivityCompat.java:371)
        at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:58)
        at androidx.navigation.ActivityKt.findNavController(Activity.kt:30)
```

I just one return from the activity that I have created to my previous fragment with safe arguments or a bundle.

I hope did be clear guys, thanks so much.